# How to sum up every 10 lines and calculate average using AWK?

Tags: awk

I have a file containing N*10 lines, each line consisting of a number. I need to sum up every 10 lines and then print out an average for every such group. I know it's doable in `awk`, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$ cat input 
1
2
3
4
5
6
2.5
3.5
4
$ awk '{sum+=$1} (NR%3)==0{print sum/3; sum=0;}' input 
2
5
3.33333
```

(Adapt for 10-line blocks, obviously.)

Comment: You could have used `seq` to abstract away the test input: `seq 50|awk '{sum += $1} (NR%10)==0{print sum/10; sum = 0;}'`

Comment: Hm, it doesn't seem to work in my case. Could the fact that I'm working on decimal values have anything to do with it?

Comment: I found what was wrong. My line didn't actually consist entirely of a number, but some textual strings before it. So in my case it should be `$4` instead of `$1`. Now it's working. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] seq 20 > test.file

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '
{sum+=$1} 
(NR%10==0){avg=sum/10;print $1"\nTotal: "sum "\tAverage: "avg;sum=0;next}1' test.file
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Total: 55   Average: 5.5
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
Total: 155  Average: 15.5
```

If you don't want all lines to be printed then the following would work.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '
{sum+=$1} 
(NR%10==0){avg=sum/10;print "Total: "sum "\tAverage: "avg;sum=0;next}' test.file
Total: 55   Average: 5.5
Total: 155  Average: 15.5
```