# Average of every two lines for all columns except the first one

Tags: macos, awk

I have a dataset that looks like this:

> item1    20     30    12
>   item1    10     50   17
>   item2    -9    112   15
>   item2    -9    100   10

The actual dataset has 101 columns. I want to print the average of consecutive values in each column (except the first column which contains names).

so expected output would be

> item1    15       40    14.5
>   item2    -9    106    12.5

I found from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551349/how-to-sum-up-every-10-lines-and-calculate-average-using-awk) that I can do this for a single column with the following code

```
awk '{sum+=$2}(NR%2)==0{print sum/2; sum=0;}'
```

But I cannot figure out how to do this for rest of the columns and print the unique row name (e.g: item1) for rows of average values. I tried something like this:

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) sum[i]+=$i} NR%2==0 {print sum[i]/2;sum[i]=0}'
```

but the code is obviously incorrect and I will appreciate if anyone could point out what am I doing wrong and how to improve it to get expected result.Thanks!

Comment: you know that `NR%2` is a modulo operator that says operate on every 2nd line? You want to perform that (with the modulo test) in an awk `END { ....} `. block. A little more looking at other examples will get you there. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum consecutive pairs of lines starting at line 2 for a dynamic number of fields:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)a[i]+=$i;if(NR%2){printf "%s ",n$1;n="\n";for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s ",a[i]/2;delete a}}' file
item1 15 40 14.5 
item2 -9 106 12.5
```

Comment: Thanks, but my actual dataset has 101 columns so I wanted to write the code to process every column with the for statement--can you kindly show me how can I do that? thanks again

Comment: can you please explain the function of this part NR==3?$1: ? If I run the above code for some reason I am getting a syntax error, and I am not sure why.

Comment: It's the ternary operator `print a?0:1` it's equivalent `if(a) print 0;else print 1` I'm guessing that you are on `Mac` and have `BSD awk` which doesn't support this feature. I have now made the script Mac friendly but you should install `GNU awk`. Please re-accept if the issue is solved.

Answer (score 2):

try this awk solution with your 101 columns file:

```
 awk 'n<2{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)a[i]+=$i;n++;}
     n==2{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)s=s sprintf("%s ",a[i]/2)
         print $1,s;s="";delete a;n=0}' file
```

if you like checking with `NR%2`, this works too:

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)a[i]+=$i}
        !(NR%2){for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)s=s sprintf("%s ",a[i]/2) 
        print $1,s;s="";delete a}' file
```

both awk lines output same with your example:

```
item1 15 40 14.5 
item2 -9 106 12.5
```

**note**

- works for dynamic number of columns
- there is a space at the end of each line, I am a bit lazy on that, if it is critical, it could be removed too.

Comment: thanks for both of the solutions--these helped me to learn more

Comment: whats the meaning of s=s before sprintf? Is vector a storaged in s? Because if I make print of s (without $1) I get de positions from 2 to NF.

Comment: @ManuelRamón `s = s concatenate the result of sprint(..)`