# Keep first duplicate and replace the rest with blank cell using Awk

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk

I have a tsv file where I have 2 columns, with duplicates in the 2nd column. What I would like to do is keep the first duplicate value and replace the rest with blanks. E.g.

Original tsv:

```
ahah.asd   aha
ahsjd.asd  aha
asdd.asda  aha
ajd.asd    aha
asdfk.lo   abb
hasd.pou   abb
hasd.asd   jjj
asidh.09   kkk
asdhs.97   kkk
```

Expected output:

```
ahah.asd   aha
ahsjd.asd  
asdd.asda  
ajd.asd    
asdfk.lo   abb
hasd.pou   
hasd.asd   jjj
asidh.09   kkk
asdhs.97
```

In addition to this I would like to add a column that increments until if see a duplicate in column 2. E.g:

```
ahah.asd   aha   1
ahsjd.asd        2
asdd.asda        3
ajd.asd          4
asdfk.lo   abb   1
hasd.pou         2
hasd.asd   jjj   1
asidh.09   kkk   1 
asdhs.97         2
```

Is this possible? I would like to use awk...

Thanks

Comment: Are the duplicate values always on contiguous lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 's!=$2{c=0;s=$2}{print $1,(c++?"":s),c}' file
ahah.asd    aha 1
ahsjd.asd       2
asdd.asda       3
ajd.asd     4
asdfk.lo    abb 1
hasd.pou        2
hasd.asd    jjj 1
asidh.09    kkk 1
asdhs.97        2
```

There's one tab between each field.

Comment: This worked really well!

Comment: `c++==0?s:""` = `c++?"":s`. Also, ternary expressions without parens will cause syntax errors in some awks in some contexts so I'd always use parens to avoid that problem and to improve readability: `print $1, (c++?"":s), c`

Comment: @EdMorton Where do ternary expressions without parents cause syntax errors? (That sounds more like a bug to me.) But I like `c++?"":s` :-)

Comment: Let me google for examples. One sec...

Comment: I can't find an example online given how much effort I'm willing to put into looking for it but with BSD awk try something like `print 5==3 ? 1 : 0` and I expect you'll get a syntax error. Whether it's a bug or undefined behavior or something else, idk, but you can work around it with parens and they always make the code easier to read so I always use them anyway.

Comment: found breadcrumbs: Note the comment at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887368/average-of-every-two-lines-for-all-columns-except-the-first-one#comment22623708_15887532 and the response to it right under it which isn't 100% correct since just adding parens would solve the problem.

Comment: Apparently `printf "%s ",NR==3?$1:"\n"$1` led to that syntax error. Here, I would definitely put parens because it's not immediately understandable if `$1` belongs to the ternary operation or not. If it looks unambiguously, I usually don't. Thanks!

Comment: That's not the only case that'll produce syntax errors though. IMHO ternary expressions are almost never immediately understandable as it takes a second to even realise you're looking at a ternary expression and **then** figure out what it means so they can always benefit from parens for readability and it has the nice side effect of making your script more portable so unless it's a game of code golf I don't see any reason to ever not use them.

Comment: @EdMorton OK, changed. I find it easier to read without parens when nothing else is involved (like `return ... ? ... : ...;` or `a = ... ? ... : ...;`), but also when it's one of the arguments, separated by a comma (but I guess that's not the case for many others).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print $1, (cnt[$2]++ ? "" : $2), cnt[$2]}' file
ahah.asd        aha     1
ahsjd.asd               2
asdd.asda               3
ajd.asd         4
asdfk.lo        abb     1
hasd.pou                2
hasd.asd        jjj     1
asidh.09        kkk     1
asdhs.97                2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` and `column`:

```
awk '{print $1,(($2 in a)?"":$2),++a[$2]}' OFS=, file | column -t -s,
```

Answer (score 0):

Portable Perl solution

```
$ perl -F'\s+' -lane ' { $p=$x{$F[1]}++;$k=$p==0?$F[1]:""; print "$F[0]\t$k\t",$p+1 } ' tsv_file
ahah.asd        aha     1
ahsjd.asd               2
asdd.asda               3
ajd.asd         4
asdfk.lo        abb     1
hasd.pou                2
hasd.asd        jjj     1
asidh.09        kkk     1
asdhs.97                2
```

**more compact:**

```
$ perl -F'\s+' -lane ' { $p=$x{$F[1]}++==0?$F[1]:""; print "$F[0]\t$p\t",$x{$F[1]} } ' tsv_file
```