# Awk: substituting each n lines with their average, for each column

Tags: awk, average

How can I substitute each n lines of a file with their average using awk?

This question answer perfectly, except for the fact that it handles only one column and the `3` is not parametrized:
[How to sum up every 10 lines and calculate average using AWK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551349/how-to-sum-up-every-10-lines-and-calculate-average-using-awk)

basically I would like to take a file like this

```
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
2.5   2.0
3.5   2.0
4     2.0
```

and obtain something like this:

```
2     1   
5     1
3.33  2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete shell script:

```
awk -v count=3 '
    {
        if ( NF > tot_col )
            tot_col = NF;

        cur = 1;
        while ( cur <= NF )
        {
            sums[cur] += $cur;
            cur++;
        }

        if ( ( NR % count ) == 0 )
        {
            cur = 1;
            while ( cur <= tot_col )
            {
                printf("%0.2f ", sums[cur] / count);
                cur++;
            }

            print "";

            delete sums;
            tot_col = 0;
        }
    }' "$@"
```

Comment: Note that there were inconsistencies in the output described in the question.  Some where printed as integers, some had .0, etc.  That was not included in the answer since it was unclear whether it was important, and if it was, what logic should be used for the formatting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. Float output for everything is OK to me

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -v rows=3 '{c1+=$1; c2+=$2} (NR%rows)==0{printf "%.2f %.2f\n", c1/3, c2/3; c1=0; c2=0}' input
2.00 1.00
5.00 1.00
3.33 2.00
```

Comment: You miss `'` in your post