# Binning a column of data with errorbars using awk

Tags: bash, awk

Say I have three columns of data in a file data.dat ( xaxis, yaxis and yerror)

```
1 21.0 0.1
2 22.0 0.2
3 23.0 0.1
4 24.0 0.2
5 25.0 0.1
6 26.0 0.2
```

I would like to bin the above data with say binwidth=2 and produce a file
data2.dat which is as follows:

```
1.5 21.5 0.15
3.5 23.5 0.15
5.5 25.5 0.15
```

Is there an awk one liner which can do the above efficiently.
I am completely new to awk, so some comments pointing in the right direction will also be useful.

I found this answer useful: It does the job.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650198/2047639

Comment: Please read [ask] then [edit] your question to include your attempt and describe the issues you are having trying to solve your problem.

Comment: There are books and online tutorials on `awk`. I don't see how we can point you in any better direction than that. The only other thing we could do is write it for you.

Comment: I guess, I was just being lazy... However, researching a bit more led me to the answer. I have edited my question accordingly.. Thanks. Lesson learnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this might not be the best way to do it , I wish to give you some guidelines :

```
awk -v var=2 'BEGIN{count=var;c1=c2=c3=0;} #code executed only at the beginning of the script
     { # This block is applied to all the records which by default is a line
     if(count>0){ #notice the c style if
     c1+=$1;c2+=$2;c3+=$3; #again c style increment
     count--
     }
     else{
     printf "%-3s %5s %5s\n",c1/var,c2/var,c3/var # Again notice any similarity with c?
     count=var;
     c1=$1;c2=$2;c3=$3
     count--;
     }
     }
     END{ #This block will be executed only after processing all the records
     printf "%-3s %5s %5s\n",c1/var,c2/var,c3/var
     }' yourfile
```

The `-v` option helps to pass variable from shell variables or user-defined variables to awk.

**Output**

```
1.5  21.5  0.15
3.5  23.5  0.15
5.5  25.5  0.15
```

A comprehensive guide to AWK programming is available at 
[[ GNU Website ]](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf).

**Note:** I passed the bin-width using `var`